# How do I compare LibGDX PolygonShapes?

Tags: libgdx, box2d, equals

How do I check if one PolygonShape is the same than an other one? `.equals()` does not work. This code does not print "equals".

```
PolygonShape test1 = new PolygonShape();
PolygonShape test2 = new PolygonShape();

test1.setAsBox(10, 20, new Vector2(0,0), 0);
test2.setAsBox(10, 20, new Vector2(0,0), 0);

if (test1.equals(test2))System.out.println("equals");
```

Comment: Well that happens 'cos `equals` method is not overridden in `PolygonShape` class. I would raise an issue on the GitHub if you really need to compare them.

Comment: I'll probably try to find a workaround. That might be easyer

Answer (score 0):

There is no pre-defined `equals` function for the `PolygonShape` class but it wouldn't be too hard to write your own. As follows:

```
boolean polygonEqual(PolygonShape a, PolygonShape b) {
    int n = a.getVertexCount();

    //If the two shapes have differing numbers of vertices they can't be equal
    if (n != b.getVertexCount()) return false;

    //Check if all the vertices are equal
    Vector vA, vB;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       a.getVertex(i, vA);
       b.getVertex(i, vB);

       if (!a.equals(b)) return false;
    }

    //Now they must be equal
    return true;
}
```

**Note:** this will only work if the ordering of vertices is also the same. It may be the case that the same vertices are in two different polygons but shifted across by some index. However, since your example uses only `setAsBox` this function should be sufficient as a comparison.

Comment: Found a workaround already. Actually the whole algorithm is much simpler now. I wanted to check if there is already a fixture with a given shape in a body, before adding a new Fixture: if(body.getFixtureList().get(i).getShape().equals(shape))...

Comment: i am now just removing the shapes, that are already contained in a body from my shapeList, so they can't be found multiple times.